# Guava cache maximum number of elements if maximumSize is not set

Tags: java, spring, caching, guava

I'm trying to figure out what the number of elements the cache can hold if I do not specify any maximum size.

Is there any upper-bound to how many entries can be contained by `cacheWithoutSize` ?

`Cache<String, Object> cacheWithoutSize = CacheBuilder.newBuilder() .build();`

I read through the release doc, could not find any answer : [https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#:~:text=maximumSize(10000)%20](https://guava.dev/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#:%7E:text=maximumSize(10000)%20).

Comment: Why do you think there's a specific limit?

Comment: Would you consider ArrayList to have a limit?  A Cache has a limit like that.  (It might cap out around Integer.MAX_VALUE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending what Louis Wasserman said...

Let's assume the absolute limit on cache size (entry count) is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is a bit over 2 billion. In realistic caching scenarios you're very likely to run out of heap memory long before you get anywhere near the theoretical maximum cache size.

For example, if we assume `Long` keys mapping to `String` values that each use 20 bytes, that's 24 bytes per entry exclusive of overhead, so a maximal cache would contain roughly 50 GiB of data. Few machines can support a 50+ GiB heap allocation. And remember that overhead (e.g., the cache data structure itself) would make the real memory usage even larger.